# click menu <li> and generate other submenu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

Friends have a problem.
When clicking a link from a menu, I need to generate below the selected sub-menu item.

So far I can send the request via ajax, and generate a sub-menu, but this sub-menu always appears in the first position:

HTML CODE (simple menu)

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="#" data-id="1" class="region_id">Item 1</a>
   <ul id="city"></ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="#" data-id="2" class="region_id">Item 2</a>
   <ul id="city"></ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="#" data-id="3" class="region_id">Item 3</a>
   <ul id="city"></ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="#" data-id="4" class="region_id">Item 4</a>
   <ul id="city"></ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="#" data-id="5" class="region_id">Item 5</a>
   <ul id="city"></ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

JS CODE:

```
$('.region_id').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $.get('{!! url("filter_city") !!}', {id : $(this).attr('data-id'), token: $('input[name="_token"]').val() }, function(data) {

       var cities = $('#city');
        cities.empty();

        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
          cities.append($("<li></li>").text(value)); 
        });

    });
});
```

Result I get when clicking any option

[image: Result]

As I can achieve what I want? Greetings from Chile

Comment: Identifier in HTML must be unique. You are using `id="city"` multiple times hence your HTML is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

Identifier in HTML must be unique. You can use a common class and then traverse DOM using various methods.

Here's an example, I have used `city` as CSS class instead of ID. then the relevant element can be identified using any of these methods.

```
var cities = $(this).next('.city');
//var cities = $(this).siblings('.city');
//var cities = $(this).closest('li').find('.city');
```

*HTML*

```
<ul>
   <li>
        <a href="#" data-id="1" class="region_id">Item 1</a>
        <ul class="city"></ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

*Script*

```
$('.region_id').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var cities = $(this).next('.city');

    $.get('{!! url("filter_city") !!}', 
        {
            id : $(this).data('id'), 
            token: $('input[name="_token"]').val() 
        }, 
        function(data) {       
            cities.empty();
            $.each(data, function(key, value) {
              cities.append($("<li></li>").text(value)); 
            });
        }
    );
});
```

I would recommend you to use `.data()` instead of `attr()` to fetch `data-*` custom attribute value.

```
var id = $(this).data('id');
```

Comment: I do not get any error console or anything, but I do not think the sub-menu, I hope you can help me. Thanks for your help and time. Greetings.

Comment: Thank you very much friend, I served me and was exactly what I wanted.
Another thing, as I can do to make a sub-menu disappears when another item on the main menu click.
Again thank you very much for your help, you are the best. Greetings from Chile.

Comment: @CristianMezaBustos, Since you are using `cities.empty();` you can do instead `$('.city').empty();`

Comment: My last question is how can I apply an effect every time it closes or opens a sub-menu (fadein and fadeout for example). Very grateful to all your help. Greetings from Chile.